# Q: Tibco BW Instance Specific variable in tra file

Tags: tibco-business-works

I am a Tibco Administrator and one of our developers is requesting for me to make a change to the tra file for a property called bw.platform.services.retreiveresources.Hostname.  I see the property defined in at the par level but since it is a hostname they need it to be defined for each Process archive we have two server instances.

The reason I don't want to make the change in the tra file is because when we deploy; the changes get lost.  We have many apps and it will be a nightmare to keep track of all these changes in the tra files every time we have a deployment.

Since I am not a develper and could you please tell me in simple terms how this can be done in Tibco without modifying the tra file. So I can pass along the info to the develpers.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This property is used to set the hostname for WSDL client retrieval and defaults to "localhost" as far as i know.
It doesn't need to be set on TRA level but could also be set in TIBCO Administrator on the Process Archive Level.

As you mentioned there are 2 instances hosted for each services (i assume on 2 different hosts).
So by that i would assume there's a load balancer configured in front that (as i would consider a good practice) would rewrite the hostnames in the wsdl by a rule.
Depending on your configuration of the bw engine boxes i would leave it to 0.0.0.0 or localhost and let the load balancer rewrite the WSDL IP to clients to not directly expose it there.

Hope that helps

Seb

Answer (score 0):

This is used to retrieve WSDL instead of  retrieve process